# ID's are not saving to DB across models/controllers in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, model-view-controller

I have a Landlord model, a LandlordCompany model, and a LandlordAddress model. I need to save the landlord_id to the landlord_comapnies table, and the landlord_company_id to the landlord_address table. I have hidden_fields to try to accomplish this which I have done in the past, but it is not working in this instance. What am I missing? Any help welcomed. Thanks in advance!

landlord.rb

```
class Landlord < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :landlord_companies
end
```

landlord_company.rb

```
class LandlordCompany < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :landlord
end
```

landlord_address.rb

```
class LandlordAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :landlord_company
end
```

_form.html.erb <- landlord_companies

```
<div class="field">
   <%= f.hidden_field :landlord_id, :value => params[:landlord_id] %>
</div>
```

_form.html.erb <- landlord_addresses

```
<div class="field">
   <%= f.hidden_field :landlord_company_id, :value => params[:landlord_company_id] %>
</div>
```

Routes.rb

```
resources :landlords do
   member do
      resources :landlord_companies do
         member do
            resources :landlord_addresses
         end
      end
   end
end
```

Landlords Controller

```
private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_landlord
  @landlord = Landlord.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def landlord_params
  params.require(:landlord).permit(:name, :rating, :contact_name, :contact_number, :listing_agent_id, :own_application, :own_credit, :accepts_roommate_matchups, :management_company)
end
```

Landlord_companies Controller

```
private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_landlord_company
  @landlord_company = LandlordCompany.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def landlord_company_params
  params.require(:landlord_company).permit(:llc_name, :landlord_id)
end
```

Landlord_addresses controller

```
private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_landlord_address
  @landlord_address = LandlordAddress.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def landlord_address_params
  params.require(:landlord_address).permit(:address_line_one, :address_line_two, :city, :state, :zip, :super_name, :super_number, :landlord_company_id, :latitude, :longitude)
end
```

Comment: Do you use strong parameters in your controllers? How do they look like?

Comment: You need to add that landlord companies have many landlord addresses.  Then when you create a new object you need to follow the docs and do something like landlord.landlord_companies.new(lord_params)

Comment: @spickermann I added them.

Comment: @bkunzi01 Add that as an answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add that landlord companies `has_many` landlord addresses. Then when you create a new object you need to follow the docs and do something like `landlord.landlord_companies.new(lord_params)`